# how to restrict only letters and numbers at p:inputMask

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, input-mask

I want to restrict my <p:inputMask> with only letters and numbers without giving any size (max-legth) limit. I tried to use mask attribute but when I use mask attriibute it gives a max-length for my inputMask. Could you please help me to solve this issue ?

Sample Code :

```
<p:inputMask value="#{gercekKrediBasvuruDetayGirisView.kisi.ticariHarfSeri}"
  required="true" mask="***" 
  requiredMessage="#{msg['GercekKrediBasvuruTuketiciMaliBilgiler.belgeSeriNull']}"
/>
```

Comment: try KeyFilter from PrimeFaces Extensions:http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/keyFilter.jsf
You can restrict input with regex and that's easier than using p:inputMask directly.

Comment: Does it have to be `<p:inputMask>` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your input does not have to be `<p:inputMask>` and can be `<h:inputText>` or `<p:inputText>` then the easiest way to go would be to use it with regex:

```
<h:inputText id="inputField" value="#{backingbean.username}" validatorMessage="Value does not match pattern.">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message for="inputField" />
```

If you only allow lower case letters go with `^[a-z0-9]+$`.
`<p:inputMask>` is designed for somewhat stricter validation than only letters and numbers.